# How to use Ruby 2.4.0 on a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run `cap production deploy` I get the following error:

```
cap production deploy

SSHKit::Command::Failed: ruby exit status: 2
ruby stdout: Nothing written
ruby stderr: Ruby ruby-2.4.0 is not installed
```

I specified the Ruby version in my deploy.rb file:

```
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.4.0'
```

and included it in my Gemfile:

```
gem "capistrano", "~> 3.8"
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano-passenger'
```

How should I run Ruby version 2.4.0 on the server without going into the server?

Comment: Your caps lock key seems to be broken. You might want to look into fixing it.  "when" -> "When", "i" -> "I", "ruby" -> "Ruby", "gemfile" -> "Gemfile". SO isn't a discussion list, it's a reference site, like an encyclopedia, where grammar, spelling and punctuation all matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this on server:

```
rvm install 2.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the Ruby version on the server using

```
rvm install 2.4.0
```

and then, in your app's root path, use the installed Ruby:

```
rvm use 2.4.0
```